# Nested for loops - @RadioButtonFor not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
for (var h= 0; h< Model.Homes.Count(); h++)
    for (var p = 0; p< Model.Homes[h].Phones.Count(); p++)

        //this works 
        @Html.RadioButton("Phone"+h.ToString(), h, Model.Homes[index].Phones[p].Phone.IsPrimary.Value)

        //Can't figure this one out
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Homes[index].Phones[p].Phone.IsPrimary, p)

    }
}
```

Realizations:

I've noticed after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list) that my code is creating a single radiobutton for each phone, but isn't tying them together based on homes.

**What am i missing?**

They either both check, or un-check but their not (bound?) *also, i can check both of them or un-check both of them*) correctly by the name of the control??

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it because I'm dealing with Boolean values???

Comment: Is your goal to allow them to only select one Phone per Home as primary?

Comment: @stephen.vakil that is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override the name attribute of a RadioButtonFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038492/how-can-i-override-the-name-attribute-of-a-radiobuttonfor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it will be possible using `RadioButtonFor` here.  `RadioButtonFor` will construct the `Name` of the radiobutton based on the lambda expression you provide.  If your model were to have a property `PrimaryPhone` then you could use `RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Homes[h].PrimaryPhone)` but the way it is here, the lambda expression will cause it to construct a name specific to each phone.

See:  [How can I override the name attribute of a RadioButtonFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038492/how-can-i-override-the-name-attribute-of-a-radiobuttonfor)

You can either use the first syntax you suggested to manually construct a radio grouping, or you could consider adding a property to your model to store the primary phone.